# Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-ami

Got these errors while installing and didn't find a specific answer for it.  So, I'm offering the solutions as I found them in case anyone else encounters this:

Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64

The problem was encountered while trying to install https (mod24_ssl) over apache version 2.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you install Apache using "yum install httpd" then you're going to get version 2.2.  If you are getting this error then that's what you have.  You'll have to upgrade to Apache 2.4.  Hopefully you aren't so far in that you'll lose any work if you just delete version 2.2:

```
sudo yum remove httpd
sudo yum remove httpd-tools
sudo yum install httpd24
```

Answer (score 0):

If you install Apache using "yum install httpd" then you're going to get version 2.2. If you are getting this error then that's what you have. You'll have to upgrade to Apache 2.4. Hopefully you aren't so far in that you'll lose any work if you just delete version 2.2:

```
sudo yum remove httpd
sudo yum remove httpd-tools
sudo yum install httpd24
```

Comment: @AdamWinter I agree this answer is bad because it is copied from the question, but you should have posted a correct self-answered question in the first place. I can kind of see where this user came from. A question _should_ properly be answered in the answer section, but EffyCoder should have made this a community wiki answer at least.

Comment: @ModusTollens thanks for pointing it out. I have made it a community wiki answer. The answer was a suffice one.  If you want to add any more value to this answer, I will be happy. Thank you.